# transform GroupBy+aggregate to groupByKey

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I work on a DF that looks like this :

```
+-------+-------------+
|A      |B            |
|1      |"foo"        |
|1      |"bar"        |
|1      |"foobar"     |
|2      |"bar"        |
|2      |"foo"        |
```

and I want to transform it to something like this :

```
+-------+-----------------+
|A      |B                |
|1      |"foo/bar/foobar" |
|2      |"bar/foo"        |
```

So, I wrote this code to do so :

```
df.groupby("A")
.agg(concat_ws("/", collect_list(col("B"))))
.collect()
```

However, since I work on a large DF, groupby+agg is not that good and does a lot of shuffling. I did some research and found that ReduceByKey could be better (less shuffling). So, my question is : how can I replace GrouBy+agg with ReduceByKey ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't replace it. Group By in Spark SQL is not the same as `Group By Key` in Spark Core. It is more complex operation.

In Spark SQL, groupBy just add a node in Query Plan. The way it will be executed is recognized during Query Plan transform from Logical Plan to Physical Plan. Spark will optimize grouping as much as it can now.

So, for now: use groupBy + agg when you can, it's the fastest solution in the most cases.

One of cases when Spark SQL is less efficient is treeAggregate - currenlty there's no such API in Spark SQL and Spark Core is faster when you need tree Aggregation. However, Community is working now on tree Aggregate also in Datasets and DataFrames

As @user8371915 mentioned in the comment, in your case there is nothing to reduce - groupBy will work exactly the same as RDD.groupByKey, because it can't aggregate values from Dataset or DataFrame. However, the key point is still the same - Spark SQL groupBy will choose how to do grouping

Comment: Thank you guys for these infos